# How to Bulk update Embedded Docs in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, bulk

Having a hard time getting MongoDB to update an embedded doc Using Bulk updates MongoDB version 3.0 any help would be of thanks.

Comment: Your question is way too broad for anyone to answer in its current state.  Please post what the issue that you're having is along with any error message and/or stack traces.  Also, please post your expected results vs actual results.

Comment: Hey Ranger no offense but unless you actually have any idea how to bulk update an embedded doc, then you're not any help and I can't find any mention of it anywhere including MongoDB docs so I don't think it can be done and instead I ended up normalizing the data

Answer (score 0):

Far as I can tell the best thing to do is unwind and normalize the output.